# (R) Generating an oauth 1.0 token for Flickr using httr

Tags: r, api, oauth, flickr, httr

I'm trying to generate an access token for my Flickr app in httr. My goal is to download images from certain geographical co-ordinates. To my understanding this isn't something the FlickrAPI package can do, so I've decided to use httr.

Running the below code brings up the authorization page but when I submit the authorization I get a localhost error (localhost unexpectedly closed the connection).

What am I forgetting here? I haven't set a callback URL, if that's relevant.

```
library(httr)

setwd("G:\\Project\\R Code\\")

api_key <- "<TOKEN>"
secret <- "<SECRET>"

flickr.app <- oauth_app("App Name", api_key, secret)

flickr.endpoint <- oauth_endpoint(
  request = "https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token",
  authorize = "https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/authorize",
  access = "https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/access_token"
)

token <- oauth1.0_token(
  flickr.endpoint,
  flickr.app,
  cache = FALSE
)
```

Comment: Forgive the question, I don't code in R, but... why not use an actual oauth 1.0 package? (e.g. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROAuth/) (sure, it's from 2015, but oauth 1.0 is from 2007. There is literally zero reason to update an oauth library once it works)

Comment: That sounds like it'd be an easier solution. So I should generate an access token for my Flickr app using something like ROAuth and then pass that access token to httr?

Comment: never having tried that, it does kind of sound like the right approach - use the oauth package to get all the oauth handshaking set up, then use a package that allows token-authenticated GET/POST calls.